# org.springframework.webflow.conversation.NoSuchConversationException while invalidating the Session

Tags: jsf, session, primefaces, spring-webflow

I am trying to invalidate a session on logout and it successfully invalidates the session. But after that I am getting this error:-

```
org.springframework.webflow.conversation.NoSuchConversationException : No conversation could be found with id '2' -- perhaps this conversation has ended?
```

here is my logout code :-

```
public void logout() throws IOException {
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
            .getExternalContext().getRequest();
System.out.println(" Whether session is destroyed or not :"+SessionCounterListener.invalidate(sessionManager.getSessionID()));
securityDao.logoutUser(gUserLoginID, userDetailTO.getUserID());
}
```

SessionCounterListener is a class which implements HttpSessionListener.

Comment: What does `securityDao.logoutUser` do? I would imagine you would have problems with doing anything within the context after invalidating the session just a line before

Comment: securityDao.logoutUser is used to update user table.

Comment: Well that wouldn't work now would it? You invalidated the session in the previous line and as a result, you've lost the context of the conversation. Invalidating the session should be the very last thing you do as a rule of thumb